# Trying to do hidden redirect with .htaccess - redirect is visible

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set something up on my local server where if I go to `mydomain/docs` it does a redirect internally to `mydomain/slate/build`, but have the user still see `mydomain/docs` in their browser's url. I have it half working - when I go to `mydomain/docs`, it loads the correct index.html in `/slate/build` but the issue is that my url bar:wq shows `mydomain/slate/build` when the desired url is `mydomain/docs`.

Here is my entire .htaccess file that does the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?docs$ /slate/build [L]
```

And here is what I believe to be potentially relevant from my apache2.conf:

```
HostnameLookups Off

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

And finally my VirtualHost in sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost mydomain>
         DirectoryIndex index.html
         ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
         DocumentRoot /correct/file/structure
         ServerName mydomain
         ServerAlias mydomain
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: is `build` a directory?

Comment: Yes it is - it's a directory with an index.html in it, which is the file I'm trying to pull up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes it is - it's a directory with an index.html in it, which is the file I'm trying to pull up.

Since it's a directory, you need to end the URI with a slash, otherwise mod_dir will kick in an *redirect the browser to the same URI but with a trailing slash*. Try changing your rule to:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?docs$ /slate/build/ [L]
```

Comment: This worked great! That is some weird behaviour that I did not expect. Thank you!